# If $f, g : \mathbb N \to\mathbb N$ are strictly increasing, $\exists n\in\mathbb N : f(g(g (n))) > g(f(n))$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f,g : \mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ be strictly increasing functions. Prove that there exists an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $$f(g(g(n))) > g(f(n)).$$

Someone care to elaborate a proposal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume the contrary holds. Then $f(g(g(n)))\le g(f(n))$ for all $n$. In particular, $g(g(n))\le g(f(n))$, implying that $g(n)\le f(n)$ for all $n$. Hence, also $g^3(n)\le f(g^2(n))\le g(f(n))$, implying that $g^2(n)\le f(n)$ for all $n$. Proceeding this way, we can show that $g^k(n)\le f(n)$ for all $k$ and all $n$, which is clearly impossible (even for a fixed $n$).

Comment: @JohnLieb If $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is strictly increasing, it has to be $n \leq f(n)$ for all $n$.

Comment: Yes. And from there it follows that $n\le f(n)$. Proof by induction: $1\le f(1)$ should be clear. Now, $f(n+1) > f(n)\ge n$, hence $f(n+1)\ge n+1$.

Comment: It does, but $f$ cannot be strictly increasing without increasing by at least $n$ in going from $0$ to $n$.